# Is it possible to fire an event in excel when a cell background color changes?

Tags: excel, vba, events

as the title says, im trying to make something happen when a cell changes its background color, lets say, from red to green, but the change event of a worksheet only gets fired when a user changes a value in a cell, is there a workaround to acomplish what im trying to do? or is it an impossible task?

Comment: No, there is no event for that

Comment: How does the background color change? Due to `conditional formatting`? If yes, you can utilize the `formatting rule` to trigger the `change event`.

Comment: WHY would it change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

(As in: it is not possible, there is no event handler available for that in VBA. Redesign your table, use formatting as a result and not as information in itself.)